# Error Hosting WebAPI on IIS7 : No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have code in my controller like below :

```
 [ActionName("GetAllProducts")]
        public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
        {
            return repository.GetAllProducts();
        }
```

and below is my routing.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Default",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

But once after hosting into IIS7, I am getting below issue.

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/ProductsWebAPI/api/GetAllProducts'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'GetAllProducts'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: shouldn't u be pointing to `api/Products/getallproducts`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably add a route just before the Default route one:

```
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "GetAllProducts",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
            );
```